# Вместо одной строки, удаляеться всё!

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

повзаимствовал вот такой код:

```
@bot.command()
async def rm_token(ctx, tk):
    author = ctx.message.author
    a = str(author.id)
    if a in kinglist:
        f = open("token.txt","a+")
        d = f.readlines()
        f.seek(0)
        for i in d:
            if i != tk:
                f.write(i)
        f.truncate()
        f.close()
        await ctx.send(f'Токен успешно удален!')
```

По идеи он должен удалять оприделенный токен из token.txt, но он удаляет абсолютно всё.

вот пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

он должен был удалить лишь Lai6uy8_3hPFPwIxLh, а удалил все токены

Comment: Также пробовал вводить вообще не существующий токен, но оно серавно удаляло всё токены

Answer (score 0, accepted):

можно так, но это первое что пришло в голову, мне не очень нравится тот факт что файл открывается дважды, но это должно работать

```py
@bot.command()
async def rm_token(ctx, tk):
    author = ctx.message.author
    a = str(author.id)
    if a in kinglist:
        f = open("token.txt", "r")
        old_token = f.readlines()
        f.close()

        with open("token.txt", "w") as file_obj:
          for token in old_token:
            token = token.strip()
            if token != tk:
              file_obj.write(token + '\n')
```

Comment: вместо открытия дважды, можно просто задать разрешение a+

Comment: Боюсь что нет, я точно не знаю, но для режима `a+` у меня не сработал `file.readlines()`

Comment: тогда ладно, пускай будет так, особо страшного в этом ничего нет